# Binding the "this" context

Tags: clojurescript

Is it possible to bind the `this` context in ClojureScript?
Right now, I am stuck passing in `this` to a higher-order function, as in:

```
(defn generateTransactFunction [this]
  (fn [item] (do stuff with this and item)))
```

This does not feel optimal! I am just learning ClojureScript, so I assume there's something I am missing.

**EDIT:**

Looks like `partial` can do the job, as in:

`(defn abc [this arg1 arg2] ())`

and passing

`(partial abc this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you can use `partial` if your `this` parameter at the beginning of the function's parameter list and remaining params will be bound later.

For cases where your `this` argument position prevents you from using `partial` you can use [anonymous function literal](http://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch) which will be more consise than function literal (`(fn [args...] body)`):

```
(defn abc [arg1 arg2 this] ...)

(do-sth #(abc %1 %2 this))
```